# iphone customizing UIButtons

Tags: iphone

how to customize the UIButton so that it will display other than the default button style.

Comment: @shabbir-ahmed - Please mark the correct answer. It motivates the users to answer more. Also, it helps users decide that they should actively answer your question or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 50.0); // You can change the x, y, width, height.
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubView:btn];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images-01.png"];

UIButton *btnGo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnGo.frame = CGRectMake(85,123, 100, 26);
btnGo.backgroundcolor = [UIColor clearColor];
btnGo. setImage:btnImage forState: UIcontrolStateNormal];
[btnGo.titleLabel setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
btnGo addTarget: self action:@selector(btnGoClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
customButton.frame = CGRectMake(899, 5, 82, 55);
customButton.tag = 123; 
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonToggleForHide) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:customButton];
```

and make event for that using

```
-(void)buttonToggleForHide{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

In interface build simply change the type from rounded rect to custom and then specify a new background image.

In code:

```
UIButton* b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background image on it, set Type=Custom in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

@shabbir 1st select the button then press cmd+1 change the button type to custom 
if it right select my answer
other way is that

```
UIButton* b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

And if you want to call image on button then use this

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]];
[button release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean display button with custom image? You can try this:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]];
[button release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = urRequiredFrame;
[button setImage:yourCustomImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubView:button];
```